# HTML (boostrap) messages are not in one line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Recently started learning HTML/CSS and it's my first attempt to build a website using Bootstrap. However, I've gotten stuck and don't know where to search for a problem. There should be 3 rows in one line but I don't know why the last one appears in a lower line...

Thanks in advance :)
[Website photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYXcA.png)

[HTML photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILvIj.png)

Comment: Please post a complete code example in your question. An image isn't going to cut it.

Comment: this is related to bootstrap grid , make sure not to have more than 12 rows ( bootstrap grid system has 12 rows at max)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 4th div isn't closed, same for the second paragraph; presumably your third as well. Also, you're putting 3 "row" divs in a row, this is not necessarily how bootstrap should be used (you want to use columns ("col-...") instead).

Answer (score 0):

### First of all

I see you're using Bootstrap 2, if your website is a new project, I recommend you to use the last version of [**Bootstrap**](http://getbootstrap.com/) *(currently 3.3.6)*, because your version is older and unmaintaned.

### The problem

That's happened because you're misusing the [**grid system**](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid), rows are for **grouping** columns *(`.span*` in Bootstrap 2)*, and each row is divided in **12 columns**, don't need to use a row every time you need a column.

That way, your markup structure for a 3 columns row *(in Bootstrap 2)*, should be something like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span4">
      <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus at cumque esse quam quaerat maiores.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
      <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus at cumque esse quam quaerat maiores.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
      <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus at cumque esse quam quaerat maiores.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In Bootstrap 3 is the same, you only have to change the classes `.span*` for `.col-*-*`

Each column have a inner padding, so you don't need to delegate columns in order to separate your content, in other cases you can use the offset classes.

### A few tips

Tips about grid system that you can find in the documentation of Bootstrap 3, that also works for you.

> - Rows must be placed within a `.container` (fixed-width) or `.container-fluid` (full-width) for proper alignment and padding.
> - Use rows to create horizontal groups of columns.
> - Content should be placed within columns, and only columns may be immediate children of rows.
> - Grid columns are created by specifying the number of twelve available columns you wish to span. For example, three equal columns would use three `.col-xs-4` *(That would be `.span4` on your case)*.

---

I hope I have been helpful,
Regards.